# If I erase my iPhone remotely, what happens to my iCloud backup?

Tags: icloud, backup, find-my-iphone, secure-erase

My iPhone 5s just got stolen and I did all the proper procedures (activated lost my iPhone on icloud.com and cancelled my data with my carrier). Am I, by any chance, in risk of erasing my phone remotely and losing my last iCloud backup?

Comment: If you cancelled data with your provider, the remote wipe command won't make it to your phone, unless it joins wifi which is unlikely.

Comment: If Find My IPhone was enabled that won't update either with data cut off.

Answer (score 1):

The backups do not get erased when you send an erase request to a phone.  You are actually preserving the back ups in the sense that if your phone doesn't have a passcode lock or the passcode becomes compromised, whoever has your phone now could start deleting things and if the phone starts  A new back up then your current backup would have less of your data on it.

The interface for deleting back up data of an iOS device is in the manage storage portion of iCloud. If you think someone has access to your iCloud account, change your password to prevent them from deleting the data.

So, unless other things happen, your back up data will be sitting in iCloud waiting for you to load it on your device if you recover it or on another device of your choosing.